# Django How to add new user_id row in django admin, by number or name in another table with same user_id, like works ForeignKey, but without in models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have Model Users with User_id and Model Subcribes with User_id, but without ForeignKey, How can I add new rows in Subscribes with hints of Users number or name in table Users, like if it would with ForeignKey? Is it possibe, to connect 2 tables like this in django admin?

Comment: Why not with a `ForeignKey`?